# VS Code: How to unwrap output of a command in integrated terminal in linux

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code, gnome-terminal

I use Ubuntu 18.4 and VS Code. I wanted to know how to unwrap output of a command in integrated terminal?

Is it possible? Also can it be done in Gnome terminal?

---

@Yedhin Answer Works, but I am unable to scroll horizontally. Which defeats the purpose of unwrapping.

Answer (score 0):

I cant quite understand your use-case yet, but still the way I would read a long single line output would be by piping it to the **less** command :

```
my_command_which_produces_long_output | less -S
```

you can do the same in your terminal emulator as well with the **less** command.

Edit : I don't know for sure why horizontal scrolling doesn't work with gnome-terminal. For me it works fine with the command `less -S`. But you can try explicitly setting scrolling by running these commands from your terminal and see if either of them gives your desired results.

- `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad horiz-scroll-enabled "true"`
- `synclient HorizTwoFingerScroll=1`

If these don't work either, then i strongly suggest you to try out dconf editor and to enable horizontal scroll in the touchpad section in it. If that too is fruitless, then change your terminal emulator something better like:

- lightweight : **st**
- fast : **alacritty**
- more gui options : **konsole/tilix**

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, I am unable to scroll horizontally. I am using Gnome Terminal. Does horizontal scrolling work for you?